# JavaFX transformations by mouse

Tags: user-interface, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am working on a Project in which I have to create an editor, which can create and transform ellipses. I understand all the necessary programming to do it with a GUI for the transformations, but it looks and feels better when all the Ellipses can be transformed by mouse. I know how to drag them, so that shouldn't be a problem, but for the transformation of the 2 radii and the rotation I have no clue.
An sketch of what I'm looking for: [image: sketch]

If the grabbing points are visible or not doesn't matter. Do any of you have a knowledge of how to do this easily or if there already is code out there?

I didn't find anything on Google(may be my average search skills though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Node in JavaFX has convenience methods to set transformations. So all you have to do is to register your desired input handlers aplly some transforms based on the mouse position.

```
ellipse.setRadiusY( radiusY );
ellipse.setRadiusX( radiusX );
ellipse.setRotate( angle );
```

See a [full example](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/9636541).

Comment: Your example shows how to rotate by using a handler for the MouseEvent, but can you somehow react to a mouse in 4 different ways all using drags? And if I have to create a Node myself, is there a way to access which part of the node the event came from? I know the theory behind all of the handlers, just not how to combine them...

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I need handlers for all the transformations. on the same ellipse. and all controlled by mouse. so I need to be able to react to what the user wants the ellipse to do. Change radiusX, radiusY, rotation and moving the ellipse. But If I use the Mouse for all the handlers on the same ellipse it will activate all the handlers at the same time, and that defeats the purpose.

Comment: You can add and remove handlers to a node at any time.

Comment: ... I didn't look at your example close enough... Everything clear now. Thanks.